# Remove style tags, CSS, scripts and HTML tags from HTML to plain text

Tags: asp.net, regex

Using regular expressions, how do I remove style tags, CSS, scripts and HTML tags from HTML to plain text.

In ASP.NET C#.

Comment: Accept your recent questions.

Comment: @vasmay, when you got a reasonable answer for your question then click on tick mark to accept the answer.

Comment: @vasmay, do you want to remove these from a .html file(s)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are looking for a regex to do this, however the following regex should do it,
if you run a regex replace:

```
<[^>]*>
```

To use this in a Regex Replace to the following:

```
string myHtmlString = "<html><body>my test text</body></html>";

string myPlainTextString = Regex.Replace(myHtmlString ,"<[^>]*>",String.Empty);
```

I recommend you use something like the Html Agility pack though - http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

as it has a method to make this even easier called "ConvertToPlainText":

```
string myHtmlString = "<html><body>my test text</body></html>";

string myPlainTextString = ConvertToPlainText(myHtmlString);
```