# C# ASP.NET regular expression control

Tags: c#, regex

I want to remove the below style tag code from the HTML and aspx file using a regular expression.

```
<style type="text/css">
    BODY { background-color:white; }
    TH { align:center; background-color:006563; color:white; font-family:arial; font-size:12pt; }
</style>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove style tags,css,scripts and html tags from html to plain text...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230834/remove-style-tags-css-scripts-and-html-tags-from-html-to-plain-text)

Comment: Accept your recent questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex can be used to remove the style tag from the Html code.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(HtmlData,
                     @"(<style[^*]*</style>)","",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Check the above code and let me know whether it is fine for you.

Comment: Why the `[^*]`? The asterisk is no special character in html. Do you perhaps mean `<style[^>]*>`?

Comment: @shivakant: str = Regex.Replace(str, "<script.*?>.*?</script>", "", RegexOptions.Singleline); this works fine

Answer (score 1):

```
//Remove scripts
str = Regex.Replace(str, "`<script.*?>`.*?`</script>`", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);  

//Remove CSS styles, if any found
str = Regex.Replace(str, "`<style.*?>`(.| )*?`</style>`", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);

//Remove all HTML tags, leaving on the text inside.
str= Regex.Replace(str, "`<(.| )*?>`", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);

//Remove \r,\t,\n
str= str.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\t", "");
```